Issue with updating `card1` and `card2` values in a "memory" game


let count_open_cards = 0;
let card1 = null;
let card2 = null;

function card_game(i) {
  // Получаем front и back по ID:
  let front = document.getElementById(`card-${i}`).querySelector('.front');
  let back = document.getElementById(`card-${i}`).querySelector('.back');

  // Переворачиваем карточку
  front.classList.add('flipped');
  front.style.transition = 'transform 2s ease-out';
  front.style.transform = 'perspective(600px) rotateY(-180deg)';
  back.style.transition = 'transform 2s ease-out';
  back.style.transform = 'perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg)';

  // Добавляем цифру, если она не была добавлена ранее
  if (back.querySelectorAll('h1').length === 0) {
    let h1 = document.createElement('h1');
    h1.className = 'back_number';

    let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (numbers.length - 1));
    h1.textContent = numbers[randomIndex];
    numbers.splice(randomIndex, 1);
    back.appendChild(h1);

    // Обновляем card1 и card2 только если они пусты или не равны текущему элементу
    if (card1 === null) {
      card1 = document.getElementById(`card-${i}`); 
    } else if (card2 === null && document.getElementById(`card-${i}`) !== card1) {
      card2 = document.getElementById(`card-${i}`);
    }

    // Увеличиваем счетчик открытых карточек
    count_open_cards++;

    console.log(card1, card2);
  }

  // Проверяем, что две карточки открыты
  if (count_open_cards === 2) {
    // Проверяем, что card1 и card2 имеют значения
    if (card1 && card2) {
      // Получаем значения цифр из открытых карточек
      const number1 = card1.querySelector('.back h1').textContent;
      const number2 = card2.querySelector('.back h1').textContent;

      // Проверяем совпадение
      if (number1 === number2) {
        // Совпадение!
        console.log('win');

        // Сбрасываем класс 'flipped'
        card1.querySelector('.front').classList.remove('flipped');
        card1.querySelector('.back').classList.remove('flipped');
        card2.querySelector('.front').classList.remove('flipped');
        card2.querySelector('.back').classList.remove('flipped');

        // Сбрасываем счетчик открытых карточек
        count_open_cards = 0;
        card1 = null;
        card2 = null;
      } else {
        // Не совпадение!
        // Перевернуть карточки через 1 секунду
        setTimeout(() => {
          // Сбрасываем класс 'flipped'
          card1.querySelector('.front').classList.remove('flipped');
          card1.querySelector('.back').classList.remove('flipped');
          card2.querySelector('.front').classList.remove('flipped');
          card2.querySelector('.back').classList.remove('flipped');

          // Возвращаем карточки в исходное положение
          card1.querySelector('.front').style.transform =
            'perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg)';
          card1.querySelector('.back').style.transform =
            'perspective(600px) rotateY(180deg)';
          card2.querySelector('.front').style.transform =
            'perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg)';
          card2.querySelector('.back').style.transform =
            'perspective(600px) rotateY(180deg)';

          // Сбрасываем счетчик открытых карточек
          count_open_cards = 0;
          card1 = null;
          card2 = null;
        }, 3000);
      }
    }
  }
}

function start_game(url1, url2) {
    // GET SIZE
    const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="sezi"]');
    var sezi;
    for (var i of inputs) {
        if (i.checked) {
            sezi = Number(i.value);
            break;
        }
    }

    // СКРЫВАЕМ МЕНЮ РАМКУ
    const ramka = document.querySelector('.div_ramka');
    if (ramka) {
        ramka.style.display = 'none';
    }

    // Создаем глобальный массив с цифрами
    numbers = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= sezi * sezi / 3; i++) {
        numbers.push(i);
        numbers.push(i);
        numbers.push(i);
    }
    // shuffle(numbers); // Перемешиваем массив numbers

    // ДОБАВЛЯЕМ КАРТОЧКИ
    const ramka_id = document.getElementById('div_ramka');
    if (ramka_id) {
        ramka_id.style.display = 'grid';

        // Устанавливаем размер сетки
        ramka_id.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${sezi}, 1fr)`;
        ramka_id.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${sezi}, 1fr)`;

        // Создаем карточки
        for (let i = 1; i <= sezi * sezi; i++) {
            let card = document.createElement('div');
            card.className = 'card center';
            card.id = `card-${i}`; // исправил ошибку в строке
            card.onclick = () => card_game(i);
            card.innerHTML = `
                <div class="front">

                        <img class='front_img' src='${url1}'>

                </div>
                <div class="back center">

                        <img class='back_img' src='${url2}'>

                </div>`;

            ramka_id.appendChild(card);
        }
    }
}


function plus( token = 1 ){
    const input = document.getElementById('number')
    tokens_inp = Number(input.value)
    input.value = tokens_inp+token
}

function minus( token = 1 ){
    const input = document.getElementById('number')
    tokens_inp = Number(input.value)
    if (tokens_inp>=1 &  !(tokens_inp-token<1)){
        input.value = tokens_inp-token
    }else{
        input.value = 1
    }
}
function shuffle(array) {
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
    }
    return array;
}
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);


body{
    background: url(/static/img/games/cards/bg1.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

  }



/* main */
.div_ramka{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);

  box-shadow: 17px 6px 15px 0px rgba(34, 60, 80, 0.39);

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto  auto;
    grid-template-rows: auto  auto;
    gap: 5px;
    align-content: space-around;
    justify-content: space-around; 


    max-width: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 500px;
    height: 100%;

    border: 10px solid #1b156a;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(85,133,228, 0.7);
    
}

button{
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
}

.stavka{
  /* background-color: red;
  border: 2px solid red; */
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  grid-row: 1/2;
  grid-column: span 2;

  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;

  input{
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    /* margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px; */
    box-shadow: 17px 6px 15px 0px rgba(34, 60, 80, 0.39);

    border: 5px solid #050433 ;
    background-color: #5B30DB;
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;

    
  }

  input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
  input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

  button{
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 5px solid #050433 ;
    background-color: #F4C336;
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
    box-shadow: 17px 6px 15px 0px rgba(34, 60, 80, 0.39);
  }
  .minus_5{
    border-radius: 30% 0 0 30%;
  }
  .plus_5{
    border-radius: 0 30% 30% 0;
  }
}
.game{
  grid-row: 2/2;
  grid-column: 1/2;

  max-width: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 50px;
  height: 100%;

  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;



input[type="radio"]{
    visibility:hidden;
    display: none;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label, .div_block{
  background-color: #F4C336;
  border: 1px solid #F4C336;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
.div_block{
  font-size: 25px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;

  background-color: #5B30DB;
  border: 5px solid #050433;
  border-radius: 25px;

box-shadow: 17px 6px 15px 0px rgba(34, 60, 80, 0.39);
  
}

label{
  padding: 0 15px;
  color: white;
}


}
.start{
  grid-row: 2/2;
  grid-column: 2/2;

  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-right: 25px;

  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #F4C336;
  border: 5px solid #B79C4C;
  border-radius: 25px;

  box-shadow: 17px 6px 15px 0px rgba(34, 60, 80, 0.39);
  transition: 1s;
}

.start:hover{
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

/* main_close */




/* card */
#div_ramka{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);

    display: none;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
    gap: 5px;
    align-content: space-around;
    justify-content: space-around;


    max-width: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 500px;
    height: 100%;

    border: 10px solid #1b156a;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(85,133,228, 0.7);
    
}
.card {
    width: 128px;
    height:  128px;
    position: relative;
    perspective: 1000px;
  }
  .front, .back {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    overflow: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    transition: transform .6s linear;

    


    button{
      max-width: 128px;
      max-height: 128px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: rgba(100, 1, 1, 0.0);
      border: rgba(100, 1, 1, 0.0); 
    }

    .back_number{
      z-index: 2;
      color: #F4C336;
      font-size: 25px;
    }
   }


   .front_img {
    max-width: 128px;
    min-width: 128px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  .back_img {
    max-width: 128px;
    min-width: 128px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
  }



  .front{
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
}

.back{
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(180deg);
}

/* card_close */
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/games/cards.css' %}">

    <div class="div_ramka">

        <div class="stavka">
            <button class="minus_5" onclick='minus(5)'>-5</button>
            <button class="minus" onclick='minus()'>-</button>
            <input  type="number" id="number" value=5>
            <button class="plus" onclick="plus()">+</button>
            <button class="plus_5" onclick='plus(5)'>+5</button>

        </div>
        <div class="game">
            <div class="div_block">
                <input id="3x3" class="3x3" type="radio" value="3" name="sezi" checked>
                <label for="3x3">3x3</label>
            </div>
            <div class="div_block">
                <input id="4x4" class="4x4" type="radio" value="4" name="sezi">
                <label for="4x4">4x4</label>
            </div>
            <div class="div_block">
                <input id="5x5" class="5x5" type="radio" value="5" name="sezi">
                <label for="5x5">5x5</label>
            </div>
            <div class="div_block">
                <input id="6x6" class="6x6" type="radio" value="6" name="sezi">
                <label for="6x6">6x6</label>
            </div>
            <div class="div_block">
                <input id="7x7" class="7x7" type="radio" value="7" name="sezi">
                <label for="7x7">7x7</label>
            </div>
            <div class="div_block">
                <input id="8x8" class="8x8" type="radio" value="8" name="sezi">
                <label for="8x8">8x8</label>
            </div>
            <div class="div_block">
                <input id="9x9" class="9x9" type="radio" value="9" name="sezi">
                <label for="9x9">9x9</label>
            </div>

        </div>
        <button class="start" onclick='start_game(url1,url2)'>Start</button>
    </div>


    <div id="div_ramka">


    </div>

    <script src="{% static 'js\update_balance.js'%}"></script> 
    <script src="{% static 'js\games\cards.js' %}"></script>

    <script>
        const url1 = "{% static 'img/games/cards/playing-card.png' %}"
        const url2 = "{% static 'img/games/cards/cards.png' %}"

        const url_updateBalance = '{% url "update_balance" %}';
        const url_permission = '{% url "permission" %}';
        const url_win_lose = '{% url "win_lose" %}';
    

    </script>



When I turn the card over, it is written to a variable, but if I turn it over again, it will not be written.
Example:

Click the first card, and it is recorded as card1.
Click the second card, and it is recorded as card2.
Click the first card which had been clicked before, and then click another card. At this moment, the second clicked card value is recorded in card1, and the first clicked card was skipped. And when you click the card for the fourth time, it will be recorded in card2. If card1 and card2 are not the same, they will be flipped back except for the first one.

let count_open_cards = 0;
let card1 = null;
let card2 = null;

function card_game(i) {
  // Получаем front и back по ID:
  let front = document.getElementById(`card-${i}`).querySelector('.front');
  let back = document.getElementById(`card-${i}`).querySelector('.back');

  // Переворачиваем карточку
  front.classList.add('flipped');
  front.style.transition = 'transform 2s ease-out';
  front.style.transform = 'perspective(600px) rotateY(-180deg)';
  back.style.transition = 'transform 2s ease-out';
  back.style.transform = 'perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg)';

  // Добавляем цифру, если она не была добавлена ранее
  if (back.querySelectorAll('h1').length === 0) {
    let h1 = document.createElement('h1');
    h1.className = 'back_number';

    let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (numbers.length - 1));
    h1.textContent = numbers[randomIndex];
    numbers.splice(randomIndex, 1);
    back.appendChild(h1);

    // Обновляем card1 и card2 только если они пусты или не равны текущему элементу
    if (card1 === null) {
      card1 = document.getElementById(`card-${i}`); 
    } else if (card2 === null && document.getElementById(`card-${i}`) !== card1) {
      card2 = document.getElementById(`card-${i}`);
    }

    // Увеличиваем счетчик открытых карточек
    count_open_cards++;

    console.log(card1, card2);
  }

  // Проверяем, что две карточки открыты
  if (count_open_cards === 2) {
    // Проверяем, что card1 и card2 имеют значения
    if (card1 && card2) {
      // Получаем значения цифр из открытых карточек
      const number1 = card1.querySelector('.back h1').textContent;
      const number2 = card2.querySelector('.back h1').textContent;

      // Проверяем совпадение
      if (number1 === number2) {
        // Совпадение!
        console.log('win');

        // Сбрасываем класс 'flipped'
        card1.querySelector('.front').classList.remove('flipped');
        card1.querySelector('.back').classList.remove('flipped');
        card2.querySelector('.front').classList.remove('flipped');
        card2.querySelector('.back').classList.remove('flipped');

        // Сбрасываем счетчик открытых карточек
        count_open_cards = 0;
        card1 = null;
        card2 = null;
      } else {
        // Не совпадение!
        // Перевернуть карточки через 1 секунду
        setTimeout(() => {
          // Сбрасываем класс 'flipped'
          card1.querySelector('.front').classList.remove('flipped');
          card1.querySelector('.back').classList.remove('flipped');
          card2.querySelector('.front').classList.remove('flipped');
          card2.querySelector('.back').classList.remove('flipped');

          // Возвращаем карточки в исходное положение
          card1.querySelector('.front').style.transform =
            'perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg)';
          card1.querySelector('.back').style.transform =
            'perspective(600px) rotateY(180deg)';
          card2.querySelector('.front').style.transform =
            'perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg)';
          card2.querySelector('.back').style.transform =
            'perspective(600px) rotateY(180deg)';

          // Сбрасываем счетчик открытых карточек
          count_open_cards = 0;
          card1 = null;
          card2 = null;
        }, 3000);
      }
    }
  }
}

function start_game(url1, url2) {
    // GET SIZE
    const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="sezi"]');
    var sezi;
    for (var i of inputs) {
        if (i.checked) {
            sezi = Number(i.value);
            break;
        }
    }

    // СКРЫВАЕМ МЕНЮ РАМКУ
    const ramka = document.querySelector('.div_ramka');
    if (ramka) {
        ramka.style.display = 'none';
    }

    // Создаем глобальный массив с цифрами
    numbers = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= sezi * sezi / 3; i++) {
        numbers.push(i);
        numbers.push(i);
        numbers.push(i);
    }
    // shuffle(numbers); // Перемешиваем массив numbers

    // ДОБАВЛЯЕМ КАРТОЧКИ
    const ramka_id = document.getElementById('div_ramka');
    if (ramka_id) {
        ramka_id.style.display = 'grid';

        // Устанавливаем размер сетки
        ramka_id.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${sezi}, 1fr)`;
        ramka_id.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${sezi}, 1fr)`;

        // Создаем карточки
        for (let i = 1; i <= sezi * sezi; i++) {
            let card = document.createElement('div');
            card.className = 'card center';
            card.id = `card-${i}`; // исправил ошибку в строке
            card.onclick = () => card_game(i);
            card.innerHTML = `
                <div class="front">

                        <img class='front_img' src='${url1}'>

                </div>
                <div class="back center">

                        <img class='back_img' src='${url2}'>

                </div>`;

            ramka_id.appendChild(card);
        }
    }
}

I have tried to reassign the elements, compare them, checked for empty variables, etc.

Please post a [mcve]. You can use a Stack Snippet to make it executable.
